# QDialog - How to remove the minimize button

Tags: qt, kde-plasma, qdialog

Qt 4.8 based, application - Issue with QDialog, minimize button

- Windows and Gnome (linux)

  - The modal dialog appears with the close button on the right top, and the minimize button is **nonexistent**.
  - The minimize option are grayed out in every dialog.
  - This makes sense, since the QDialog is modal - if you minimize it, the whole application will be blocked.

But here comes the issue:

- in KDE (linux) the minimize-maximize button appears.

It seems that this is a platform dependent feature -

I am not quite sure on what do do.

Any ideas...? (I tried already with a few windowsFlags but could not find the one set that works.

Tried:

- setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint );
- Qt::WindowFlags flags = getWindowFlags( ); flags |= Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint; setWindowFlags(flags)

--- But the basic question is why the behavior on Windows/GNOME is different from KDE

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint );
    Qt::WindowFlags flags = getWindowFlags( ); flags |= Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint; setWindowFlags(flags)


** But the basic question is why the behavior on Windows/GNOME is different from KDE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want the MainWindow don't have any buttons on top use this in constructor of MainWindow:

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::SubWindow);
```

and if you want to remove just the minimize button use this:

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog);
```

Comment: This only works if you set the parent of the QDialog object; Note that it does not remove the maximize button. (this is a KDE only behavior)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html):

> In Linux with KDE this code make a window without an close and
>   minimize and maximize buttons in title bar.
>
> ```
> setWindowFlags( Qt::Dialog | Qt::WindowTitleHint );
> ```

Comment: Two Issues Here: (a) This only works if you set the parent of the QDialog object; (b) This code removes the minimized button, but not the maximize.